# Python3, how to check whether some dictionary value in list?

Tags: python, list

```
list = [
    {'a': 'a_first', 'b': 'b_first'},
    {'a': 'a_sec', 'b': 'b_sec'},
    {'a': 'a_third', 'b': 'b_third'}
]
```

I want to know value `'b_sec'` is in list's key `'b'`.

Example:

```
if 'b_sec' is in list's value of 'b':
    print('found')
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), Python's built-in function to check if a condition holds for, well, `any` out of many. `any` breaks early and avoids spurious iterations once the first truthy element is encountered:

```
if any(d.get('b') == 'b_sec' for d in lst):  # do not use 'list' as a name
    # do stuff
```

Using `d.get('b')` instead of `d['b']` is more robust as it won't raise an error if `'b'` is not in one of the dicts. Note, that if by any chance, the value you are looking for were `None`, you would have to provide a different default value to `get`, e.g. `d.get('b', '')`.

Comment: using `get` without a fallback value kinda defeats the purpose, doesn't it?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis That makes `None` the implicit fallback, which is fine since `None != 'b_sec'`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> 'b_sec' in [d['b'] for d in list]
True
>>> 'b_fourth' in [d['b'] for d in list]
False
```